# Clojure/ClojureScript and .cljc how they all interact together?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am confused about the `.cljc` file format. I was wondering if inside a `.cljc` source file can Clojure and ClojureScript functions interact together. Also I was wondering if I can call from `cljc` to `clj`, `cljs` source file. For example if I define a function inside a .cljc source file can I call that function from the ClojureScript source file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering if inside a .cljc source file can Clojure and
>   ClojureScript functions interact together.

Yes, that's possible and especially trivial if the common code is platform independent, for example:

```
(defn my-reduce [xs]
  (reduce + xs))
```

All of the functions and forms in the above code exist in both ClojureScript and Clojure, so you don't need to do anything extra to make it work.

It is also possible to include platform dependent sections of code, by using [reader conditionals](https://clojure.org/guides/reader_conditionals):

```
(ns my-namespace.foo
  (:require
    [clojure.string :refer [split]]
    #?(:clj [clojure.data.json :as json])))

(defn to-json [x]
  #?(:cljs (clj->js x)
     :clj (json/write-str x)))
```

In the above code, the standard reader conditional `#?` is used.

> if I define a function inside a .cljc source file can I call that
>   function from the ClojureScript source file?

Yes, absolutely, but just be careful to ensure that the code that you call doesn't include any JVM-specific code.

In my code example, you could call `to-json`, from either ClojureScript or Clojure because I've been careful to isolate the platform differences inside reader conditionals.

Comment: Ok I understood that , but for example can I share a deref atom from my cljs source file to cljc? I just started with Clojure/Script and I got some details that confuse me.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Data can flow both ways. There's nothing particularly magic about .cljc files. If the host platform can load and parse them, then they'll work the same as any other .clj or .cljs file, provided that you don't mix platform calls. e.g. don't try and construct a java.net.URI from ClojureScript. Maybe it will help if you just think of .cljc files as being potentially both .clj and .cljs files at the same time... which they are.

Comment: What I want to do, is depending on a bool value (of an  atom)  from cljs to trigger a clojure event for example to print in repl. Is this possible?

Comment: Ahh, no, if I correctly understand what you're suggesting, then you can't do that directly. This is because at runtime, your .cljs code is running in a different process (either a browser thread or inside Node.js) to the .clj code in the JVM. Both processes can share common code, but they don't run inside the same memory space.To communicate between the two processes you'd need to send some kind of message, for example, a REST call over HTTP.  I'm sorry that I didn't fully catch your drift right away. I hope that at least I've helped fill in a little more background on .cljc files, anyway.

Comment: Yes, you did and I'm thankfull! So if I understand it correctly if I want that kind of comunication between the two languages I need to implement an 'api'  with a handler for the request, something like [datascript] (https://github.com/tonsky/datascript) an in memory db to handle state, correct?

Comment: Actually something like [link this](https://zaiste.net/posts/web_applications_in_clojure_all_the_way_with_compojure_and_om/) would work with compojure?

Comment: Yes, most web apps are based on top of Compojure, so you're bound to need that (even if indirectly via another lib dependency). If you're new to Clojure and ClojureScript, and building a simple web app, then I'd recommend using a web application template to get started, otherwise you could get really bogged down in the difficulties of setting up the configuration and wiring between components. There are lots of good templates to choose from, but I've had good results with *Luminus* and the `+cljs`, `+reagent` profiles from here: http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/profiles.md.